# Port a library written for BB7 to BB10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I have developed an User-Authentication Library on BB7.

It constructs the UI for the Login Screen and authenticate the user from the server after credentials are entered.

I want to know that is there any change present in the BB10 development from BB7 development ? As I want to use this library for my BB10 app also .

Thanks.

Comment: Everything changed.  You'll have to write the entire library over again, in a different language.  I know ... we all feel your pain :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a series of three (at the moment) articles on [porting BlackBerry Java applications to Cascades](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/01/port-java-to-cascades-part-1/), if that helps.